# Why does HTML5 Boilerplate need jQuery? What does it do?

Tags: jquery, html5boilerplate

I am working on improving my CSS skills. For a new personal practice project, instead of a larger front-end framework, I decided to go with HTML5 Boilerplate.

I see in the project website and the GitHub repo that jQuery is used.
I do not understand why jQuery is used and what it does with this project.

I want to know:

- Why does HTML5 Boilerplate need jQuery?
- What are the features of jQuery that are used by HTML5 Boilerplate?

Comment: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1944

Comment: That github is really the answer, coming straight from the developers mouth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It serves no purpose, other than being included in the project.

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/doc/js.md

> This file can be used to contain all your plugins, such as jQuery plugins and other 3rd party scripts for a simple site

**"such as"**. It's not used at all.

Since it's a boilerplate, most people might want to include it in their project. They simply did it for you.

Comment: Let me know why this deserves a downvote, when it answers his question 100%.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I upvoted you and accepted it. I have no idea people are downvoting both your answer and my question.

Comment: @Phil Thanks. Might be because it's relatively easy for a developer to look at the code and determine it's not being used.